# If I have $ \lim_{x\to\infty} ( f(x)/g(x) ) = L$ where $L$ cannot equal $0$, can I conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty} ( g(x)/f(x) ) = 1/L ?$

Tags: calculus, limits

If I have $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=L$ where $L$ cannot equal $ 0$, can I conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right ) = \frac{1}{L} ? $
I'm just not sure if this is a valid move or not.

Comment: Yes. It seems ok.

Comment: Yes, it is OK.Taking limit is a very frienly operation.. Limit can be distributed both over sum and product other mathematical operations get distributed over one only.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use the fact that $h(x) = 1/x$ is continuous away from $x=0$ and so
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} h\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)
 = h\left( \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)
$$

Comment: I was just typing up this exact answer. I even used $h$ for the function.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins :) sorry to type it in faster

Answer (score 2):

The limit of the quotient of two functions is the quotient of their limits, provided that the limit in the denominator function is not zero.  Apply that rule to the functions $t(x)=1$ and $b(x)=f(x)/g(x)$.